# How to query for valid integer when its stored as varchar in sql?

Tags: sql

I cloned .csv file into my database table in SQL, and example data looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "year": "1955",
        "rank": "1",
        "company": "General Motors",
        "revenue": "9823.5",
        "profit": "806"
    },
    {
        "year": "1955",
        "rank": "2",
        "company": "Exxon Mobil",
        "revenue": "5661.4",
        "profit": "584.8"
    },
```

Some of the profit columns have "N.A.", and also NEGATIVE integers but these values are all stored as "strings" or VARCHAR in the SQL tables..

so how can I query for data that is a number or not equal to "N.A." (Basically I just want data that includes any integer positive or negative) in sql? I've tried ISNUMERIC() but it says I need to do type cast?

sql

Comment: You should TAG your specific database platform.

Comment: Databases have different methods. It would be helpful if you could specify which one you're using. SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: >> `try_parse()`

Comment: Is that a JSON array stored in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL or MariaDB and only interested in decimal numbers, you could use CAST like this:

```
SELECT CAST(profit as DECIMAL(5,2)) as profit_mod;
```

This will give you 0.00 for non-numeric values. Or you can cast as INTEGER to get integers - or 0 for non-numeric values.

Depending on your sql variety, you may have different options.

Comment: No, this will return an error in some RDBMS: [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad4e26501af5d78203e4e0a3a3b9bc79), [postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad4e26501af5d78203e4e0a3a3b9bc79), [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4200abc1ae92fb4695bcd29b0830c53)